# Centralizer of derived subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory

In all questions suppose $G$ metabelian p-group such that

- G is not regular ( so $cl(G) \geq p$ ), G is not a wreath product;
- $Z(G) \leq \phi(G)$.

1) Let $M$ normal abelian subgroup of $G$ such that $\frac{G}{M} \cong C_{p^{n}}$ with $n \geq 2$. So it exists an element $g \in G - M$ such that $G=M\langle g\rangle$ and  $g^{p^{n}} \in M$. Looking at $G'=[G,G]$, I showed that $G'=[M,g].$ Is it true, under these assumptions, that $C_{G}(G')=MZ(G)$ ?

2) If the answer is no, is there some other assumption for which my thesis is true?

3) In every metabelian p-group G, since G' is abelian, we have that $G' \leq C_{G}(G')$. Are there suitable assumptions for which  $G' = C_{G}(G')$? I know that this is true when $G'$ is maximal (but this means G cyclic) and when $G'$ is maximal over normal abelian subgroups.

I edited my post since it was not clear, i apologize for this fact, and i'm grateful for your attention to my problem.

Best regards

Marco, PhD student

Comment: For (1), no; say $G$ is the nonabelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$, generated by $x$ and $y$; the center equals the commutator, $\langle [x,y]\rangle$; take $M=\langle [x,y],y\rangle$, so $G/M\cong C_p$. Then $MZ(G)=M$ because $Z(G)=[G,G]\subseteq M$, but $C_G(G')=C_G(Z(G))=G$.

Comment: The second and third questions are too imprecise. To get helpful answers you need to ask more directed questions.

Comment: @MarcoRuscitti: If you are "really" looking for a counterexample with more conditions, then you need to **state those conditions**. Otherwise, you are wasting everyone's time, including yours. State *exactly* what you want, with what conditions, rather than pose a question and then complain that the answers are not really what you want. Don't just add it in the comments, edit your question and put **everything** you want in the question.

Comment: (1) is still false; take $G = \langle x,y \mid x^8=y^8=[x,y]^2=[x,y,x]=[x,y,y]=1\rangle$. So $Z(G)=\langle x^2,y^2,[x,y]\rangle$, and $[G,G]=\langle x,y\rangle$. Take $M=\langle x,[x,y]\rangle$ so that $G/M\cong C_4$. Since $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$ (being class $2$), then $C_G(G')=G$, but $MZ(G)=\langle x,y^2,[x,y]\rangle\neq G$. More generally, take any nonregular group of class two with central quotient isomorphic to $C_{2^n}\times C_{2^n}$, and pick $M$ to the be the pullback of one of the cyclic factors; then $MZ(G)=M\neq G$, but $C_G(G')=G$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I agree that when $[G,G] \subseteq Z(G)$ we have that $C_{G}(G') =G$, but in class greater than $p$ ($G$ not regular) this is not necessarly true. I'm wrong?

Comment: @MarcoRuscitti: $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$ if and only if $G$ is of class at most $2$. But $2$-groups of class $2$ are not necessarily regular, and I think the example I give is not regular, since $(xy)^2 = x^2y^2[y,x]$ cannot be written as $x^2y^2c$ where $c$ is a product of squares of commutators; if you want to put *even more* conditions (such as that the class must be strictly larger than $p$) then of course you won't have $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$, but I still don't see why the conclusion would necessarily hold. I'd try a similar example with a group of class $3$ along lines of final sentence.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  Ok, i'm grateful for your answers. I'm sorry for my mistakes writing the question, it will never happen again. Thank you again, Marco.

Comment: In Qn 3, for a metabelian $p$-group $G$, the following three conditions are equivalent: (i) $C_G(G')=G'$; (ii) $G'$ is maximal as an abelian subgroup of $G$; (iii) $G'$ is maximal as a normal abelian subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Regular 2-groups are abelian. So your second example is not regular.

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahi: I seemed to remember something like that; thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @DerekHolt i'm grateful for your answer, i had not found this results in my books.

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahi thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the material in the comments so that the question does not appear as unanswered...

(1) The first question has a negative answer as stated. For example, take 
$$G = \langle x,y\mid x^8=y^8=[x,y]^2=[x,y,x]=[x,y,y]=1\rangle$$
a $2$-group of order 128 and class $2$. Take $M=\langle [x,y],x\rangle$, so that $G/M$ is of order $8$. Since $Z(G)=\langle x^2,y^2,[x,y]\rangle$, then $MZ(G) = \langle x^2,y,[x,y]\rangle\neq G = C_G(G')$.

Question (2) seems a bit harder to answer precisely.

For Question (3), [Derek Holt](https://mathoverflow.net/users/35840/derek-holt) provides the following:

**Proposition.** *Let $G$ be a metabelian $p$-group. The following are equivalent:*

1. $C_G(G')=G'$.
2. *$G'$ is maximal among abelian subgroups of $G$.*
3. *$G'$ is maximal among abelian normal subgroups of $G$.*

*Proof.*  (1)$\implies$(2) If $G'\subseteq A$ with $A$ abelian then $A\subseteq C_G(G')$. Hence $G'=A$.

(2)$\implies$(3) Immediate.

(3)$\implies$(1) That $G'\subseteq C_G(G')$ follows because $G$ is metabelian. And any subgroup of $G$ that contains $G'$ is normal; so if $x\in C_G(G')$, then $\langle G',x\rangle$ is abelian and normal, so by maximality $x\in G'$. $\Box$